# How to make templates of profiles in websphere?

Tags: templates, weblogic, websphere, profile

I am aware that we can make templates of domains in weblogic very easily using config_builder script. Is there a similar thing in websphere?

Answer (score 2):

I know nothing about WebLogic, but fix pack 9 for WebSphere added something you may find useful. The wsadmin command `AdminTask.extractConfigProperties` with `GenerateTemplates` and `PortablePropertiesFile` options set to true will generate a portable, editable file transferable to another cell.  `AdminTask.applyConfigProperties` is used to read your edited output and apply the properties to a new cell, server, etc.  I haven't tried this yet outside of a controlled sandbox environment; so, I'm not sure what pitfalls may await you.  But if you have a ton of servers to build, it may be worth your time to do some experimentation.

Here's the [IBM doc](http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=compass&product=was-nd-dist&topic=txml_portable_prop) on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know i don't think there is such a capability.

You can use the default product shipped profiles to start with and create the servers and configure them the way you want.

These servers can then be used as a template to build other servers.

I am  not sure if this helps you but i thought i would point this out.

Manglu